# exec sp_configure 'clr enabled' not working on Azure SQL DB

Tags: database, azure-sql-database, paas

How can I disable clr and remote access on Azure Paas DB that was migrated from Azure SQL on IaaS?

`exec sp_configure 'clr enables'` not working on SQL PaaS DB and I need to disabled clr and remote access.

Comment: "not working" isn't a clear statement; if something isn't working *explain* why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

CLR is not supported on Azure SQL Database as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server?view=azuresql), so you don't need to disable CLR on Azure SQL. In PaaS, only Azure Managed Instance supports CLR.

About configuring "Remote Access", that is a deprecated feature on SQL Server and is not available on Azure SQL PaaS as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16).